# XSS in HOST header

Tags: xss

I'm able to inject JavaScript payload in HOST header, a request will look like:

```
Host: <script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
```

Cookie got alerted with no problem.

My question is: is this exploitable? Or is it a Self-XSS because I don't know how to send the victim a specific HOST header?

Comment: Where and how are you modifying the host header? Is the server returning the javascript? Are you using greasemonkey to modify the page as it sits in your browser?

Comment: Technically, it is some kind of [code injection](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/94.html). However, since I don’t see a way to make a victim’s browser to send this *Host* header field value to a specific server, I wouldn’t call it Cross-Site Scripting.

Comment: it may have no exploit in standard browsers, but that doesn't make it unexploitable and it doesn't make it not-xss. It simply makes it unexploitable in standard browsers. Other clients may be exploitable. Some nonstandard browser may be vulnerable. That does lower the risk possibly to the point of being uninteresting, but, again, doesn't mean it's not xss.

Comment: Thanks atk \n
Gumbo : i think it is possible to make a request with javascript(xmlhttprequest) and set the header HOST to our payload , then it may be exploitable then.

Comment: @user1675137 Only if it does not follow the [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) as you are [not allowed to set *Host* request header field](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method).

Comment: Furthermore, the response of a XHR is not rendered but just returned. So the embedded JavaScript won’t be executed.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers are like any other user data, and should be sanitized by webapplications.

You might be able to use it to XSS yourself when you go to a "whats my ip" kind of website that displays this kind of information, if it's been built by developers who assumed HTTP headers are OK to send back to the user.

I've seen happen in a webapplication to view logs of server traffic. So if you can find an application that stores the HTTP headers, *and* is stupid enough to return them in HTML unsanitized, *and* it's displayed to someone other than who sent the headers, then yes it's exploitable. But again, this is like any other user data.

Comment: I know the headers are like any user data , but i never someone who stored headers in html file . in my case , when changing the header, an error message appear (NOT VALID {HEADER}) . i think in this case noting is exploitable  . Thanks Philipp

Comment: `Host` is (normally) the *name* of the *server*, so a whats-my-ip site would not use it for *client IP*. (But the possible vectors for webapp in general still apply.)

Answer (score 0):

Improper escaping/encoding (which in this case leads to XSS vulnerability) could be exploited. The main condition which must occur is improper HTTP cache handling.

If tested webapplication is vulnerable to HTTP cache poisoning, then your are able to exploit your XSS-finding.

1. Attacker sends own Host header to the webapplication.
2. Cache "saves" that fake-header and serves the evilly-modified content to other users.
3. Attacker repeats the attack.

More info. about HTTP cache poisoning could be find [here](http://www.skeletonscribe.net/2013/05/practical-http-host-header-attacks.html)